# Loop read character vector in order it was produced vs alphabetical

Tags: r, loops

Ok so I pulled a list of tickers from a sorted data frame which was sorted by date. Thus my symbols character vector is in a sorted order:

```
> tickers
  [1] "SPPI" "ZGNX" "ARDM" "PRTK" "GTXI" "HEB"  "FCSC" "ACOR" "ALKS" "MNKD" "HRTX" "CTIC"
 [13] "ARLZ" "JAZZ" "VVUS" "DEPO" "OREX" "PLX"  "PTIE" "DRRX" "SGEN" "PCRX" "PSDV" "ALIM"
 [25] "INCY" "ATRS" "INSY" "CRIS" "CORT" "EBS"  "RGEN" "ARNA" "AMRN" "HALO" "NAVB" "SUPN"
 [37] "EXEL" "IPXL" "IMGN" "DVAX" "SCMP" "TTNP" "ENDP" "AVDL" "AVEO" "TBPH" "DCTH" "ABBV"
 [49] "AMAG" "VNDA" "BMRN" "MDCO" "OMER" "BDSI" "EGRX" "ACRX" "KERX" "NKTR" "PGNX" "AEZS"
 [61] "ENTA" "BCRX" "ADMS" "VRTX" "NBIX" "RMTI" "ADMP" "AMGN" "MNTA" "PTX"  "EBIO" "NYMX"
 [73] "VTL"  "TTPH" "MACK" "LPTX" "GWPH" "SPHS" "RPRX" "OTIC" "NEOT" "CHRS" "ZFGN" "NEOS"
 [85] "RDHL" "PTLA" "OPK"  "CHMA" "ACAD" "NLNK" "AZN"  "ICPT" "AAAP" "DERM" "OCUL" "MRNS"
 [97] "RVNC" "CLVS" "GALE" "LPCN" "TSRO" "AMPE" "CYTR" "RARE" "MCRB" "ADMA" "IONS" "VTVT"
[109] "AUPH" "EARS" "ACRS" "KMDA" "RIGL" "KPTI" "TNXP" "AERI" "NVAX" "VICL" "SRPT" "GILD"
[121] "ITCI" "GNCA" "ABUS" "CEMP" "TENX" "ALNY" "PLXP" "PTN"  "INNL" "ANTH" "CRBP" "BSTC"
[133] "REPH" "NOVN" "CERC" "HTBX" "LXRX" "HZNP" "SGYP" "OPHT" "AKAO" "LIFE" "PRTO" "VCEL"
[145] "IRWD" "PBMD" "AMPH" "PFE"  "AGRX" "EGLT" "ADHD" "FGEN" "AGN"  "GEMP" "OCRX" "CATB"
[157] "DMTX" "AVIR" "JNJ"  "TCON" "SAGE" "ZSAN" "AXON" "MRK"  "VRX"  "ARDX" "XBIT" "CDTX"
[169] "TRVN" "CELG" "CMRX" "ARGS" "LJPC" "NDRM" "PBYI" "SCYX" "PTCT" "GALT" "KURA" "AKCA"
[181] "TGTX" "NVS"  "CPRX" "LLY"  "GNMX" "BLRX" "XENE" "FOMX" "SNY"  "REGN" "RTTR" "CARA"
[193] "NVCR" "BMY"  "ONCE" "GERN" "MESO" "OMED" "MTFB" "EIGR" "ACHN" "AKTX" "XOMA" "CAPR"
[205] "RDUS" "NTRP" "BPMX" "TXMD" "BTX"  "GSK"  "CORI" "FOLD" "BLPH" "SBPH" "NVO"  "RETA"
[217] "ECYT" "IMDZ" "MTNB" "ARQL" "LOXO" "ZYME" "RNN"  "PIRS" "FPRX" "CALA" "BGNE" "BLUE"
[229] "CLSN" "CRVS" "GLYC" "JUNO" "IOVA" "RGLS" "XLRN" "ALDX" "EPZM" "SELB" "IMUC" "BLCM"
[241] "GBT"  "STML" "AGIO" "RARX" "ALDR" "ITEK" "IMRN" "QURE" "SVRA" "KDMN" "CBAY" "BVXV"
[253] "CYTX" "NVIV" "MYOK" "ZYNE" "ESPR" "GLPG" "ABIO" "CVM"  "STDY" "CLLS" "INSM" "VSTM"
[265] "VYGR" "VRNA" "UTHR" "ARRY" "BPMC" "IDRA" "INO"  "EPIX" "AGEN" "FENC" "MRTX" "INVA"
[277] "NBRV" "VSAR" "IPCI" "PRQR" "AZRX" "PRTA" "BHVN" "MYL"  "FLXN" "ANAB" "RXDX"
```

I want the loop to read this character vector in the order it was produced vs alphabetic.

If I illustrate the loading of data with:

```
# Note function is store list of commands to perform over a directory of files

genCHART = function(x){  
  next.symbol <- tickers[i]  # specify to start from first position in vector
  date.list <- dates[i] # specify to start from first position in vector
          next.file <- fread(paste0("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=",next.symbol,"&outputsize=full&apikey=6RSYX9BPXKZVXUS9&datatype=csv"))
          new.df <- data.frame(next.file)
          head(new.df)
}

# Loop calls function in order to process multiple files
        for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
            genCHART(tickers[[i]])
        }

    # loop will do nothing but process and load all tickers.. but its too illustrate the point.
```

What we see if we print tickers[i]

```
> next.symbol
[1] "ANTH"
```

it gives me the first ticker per its alphabetical order. So it returns tickers beginning with A first versus my order above. I want it to loop through my character list as the the order of the ticker vector.

Is there anyway to over come this?

## Editing post

```
IF I take a vector of dates: 
> dates
  [1] "2009-07-05" "2009-07-16" "2009-07-16" "2009-09-04" "2009-10-09" "2009-11-02"
  [7] "2009-11-02" "2009-12-01" "2009-12-18" "2010-01-22" "2010-01-27" "2010-03-15"
 [13] "2010-03-15" "2010-03-19" "2010-04-09" "2010-04-30" "2010-10-11" "2010-10-28"
 [19] "2011-01-19" "2011-01-28" "2011-02-01" "2011-02-25" "2011-04-29" "2011-06-22"
 [25] "2011-06-24" "2011-06-24" "2011-08-19" "2011-10-31" "2011-11-11" "2011-11-11"
 [31] "2011-11-16" "2011-11-23" "2011-12-08" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-30" "2012-02-17"
```

and I want to start from the first in the vector...

```
date.list <- dates[i] # specify to start from first position in vector
```

shouldnt the above work even though it is wrapped in a function?

How can I get it work so that I read the start of my vector, and also how does this work when im putting my code in a function and then running the function in loop to process multiple files?

Comment: There is no loop in your code. Also, where is `i` defined?

Comment: whoops - i call this function in a loop... let me edit

Comment: `function(x)` should probably be `function(i)`.

Comment: i is defined in the loop where I call the function.

Comment: Well, what you show loops through the vector in its order and not in alphabetic order.

Comment: But then you call it passing `tickers[[i]]`, not `i`. Therefore, it should be `next.symbol <- x`.

Comment: @AndrewBannerman Not really..you called the argument `x`, so `tickers[[i]]` will be fed into `x`, which doesn't do anything in your function. Perhaps you meant: `genCHART = function(x){ next.symbol <- tickers[x] ...}` and `dfs = list(); for (i in 1:length(tickers)){ dfs[[i]] = genCHART(i) }`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  `"ANTH"` isn't even the first ticker alphabetically; `"AAAP"` is.  Something else in your code is influencing the outcome.  Do you reuse `i` elsewhere?

Comment: I see - > next.symbol <- tickers[x]
> next.symbol
[1] "SPPI" "ZGNX" "ARDM" "PRTK" - is the order.... but how to isolated the first.... Seems I have more issues than I imagined!

Comment: @Roland - that did the trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(i)` was `=` to `3`

```
i=1
```

was the answer